# How do I get out of root@ubuntu:~#

Tags: filesystem

I powered off my pcDuino system and now I am getting errors and eventually ending up in `root@ubuntu:~#`. When I try to "exit" the root super user it only shows my last login on tty1 as being in root. I was just in file manager or text editor when I powered down. I have no idea how I got to root or how to get out of it and back to my normal account.

I edited the network file per instructions:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file  used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto  lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

change to:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 init dhcp
```

Somehow that left an `/etc/network/interfaces.swp` swap file out there.
I have been getting:

```
[13.998774] init: Plymouth main process (77) terminated with status 127
{14.053176} init: ureadahead main process (79) terminated with status 5
but the system would come up after a delay.
```

I am trying to develop a STABLE and SECURE commercial product on the pcDuino3.

Typing `startx` ran several messages across the screen VERY FAST and then killed the system. I am sorry I have no idea what this thing is running. The ads say Ubuntu 12 but now I get a screen saying Linaro 12.07 (GNU/Linux 3.4.79+ armv71). I have whatever was shipped preinstalled on a pcDuino3. I hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** "Some error" can be quite easily fixed by doing "something". (cheeky way of saying that we need more info like exact kernel version, error messages, ... so please [edit] your question as now the question is **too broad to answer concisely**.

Answer (score 0):

**You probably will need to backup and reinstall your system.**

(There should be an error that causes your boot to drop into shell. Not unless you're willing to tinker with the system, then the easiest path is probably just to reinstall your system.)

Where to start tinkering:
**Type `startx`** on the tty and see what the error says and follow troubleshooting from there.